# Next.JS: How to make ALL requests server-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, server-side, next.js

I am building a [Next.JS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) app that will be getting data from a Python API and an Postgres Database.

Normally this would be simple, except requirements are such that I need to send all requests from the server-side, not the user's client.

I have been working with and grokking [`getInitialProps`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle), but I am not confident that it is the full solution that I need because of this line in the `README`:

> For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will execute on the server only. `getInitialProps` will only be executed on the client when navigating to a different route via the Link component or using the routing APIs.

It seems that `getInitialProps` is designed for the initial page load, and not for subsequent server-side data fetching.

How can I design my Next.JS app in such a way that all requests come from the server-side?

Notes:

- It is OK that every request essentially results in an initial page load.
- It is OK for the user Client to talk back to the Node (Next.JS) server since it's publicly-exposed.  I am currently experimenting with wrapping Next.JS in an [express server](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/custom-server-express).

Ty in advance for any help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a solution by wrapping Next.JS in Express!

I have pushed a simple example project to GitHub [here](https://github.com/AuthorOfTheSurf/server-side-requests-next-with-express)

The repo has a nice README as well as comments in the code that detail what's going on.

Quick rundown:

- Wrap Next.JS in an express server. Explicitly render pages by calling `nextApp.render(...)` which happens implicitly in standard Next.JS apps. See [server.js](https://github.com/AuthorOfTheSurf/server-side-requests-next-with-express/blob/master/server.js)
- Use express routing. Make server-side requests prior to rendering the pages with `nextApp.render(...)`. See [server.js](https://github.com/AuthorOfTheSurf/server-side-requests-next-with-express/blob/master/server.js).
- Use standard anchor tags to ensure that pages requests hit the express server. See [index.js](https://github.com/AuthorOfTheSurf/server-side-requests-next-with-express/blob/master/pages/index.js)
- `nextApp.render` provides passed values to the page in the context (`ctx`) parameter of `getInitialProps`. You can make these values available in the pages `this.props` by returning them in `getInitialProps`. See [stars.js](https://github.com/AuthorOfTheSurf/server-side-requests-next-with-express/blob/master/pages/stars.js)

Suggestions and improvements welcome!

Comment: Good job! It's similar to Razzle

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is done simply with `getServerSideProps()` [Official Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering). It's as simple as it says really: "If you export an async function called getServerSideProps from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page on **each** request using the data returned by getServerSideProps"

Answer (score -1):

This is generally a bad idea.

The entire point of an SPA is to prevent full page loads.

You can use `getInitialProps` to fetch stuff while on the initial page request, and on subsequent navigations, as it is called for every page.

Next is encouraging you to use an API to talk to the server