# Storing Sanity token as a secret with Now doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, sanity

I am trying to store a Sanity token as a secret when deploying my project with Now, but it all doesn't seem to work. Here is my situation:

1. I added my Sanity token as a secret to the CLI (I called it `sanity_token`).
2. I added a `now.json` file in the root of my project:

   ````
   {
       "version": 1,    
       "build": {
           "env": {
               "SANITY_TOKEN": "@sanity_token"
           }
       },    
       "env": {
           "SANITY_TOKEN": "@sanity_token"
       }            
   }```
   ````
3. I used the variable in the `sanity.js` as:

   ```
   ...
   token: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN,
   ...
   ```

...but it doesn't seem to work neither when running `npm run dev` nor when deploying it with `now`. The page gets loaded and there are no errors, but I got no content because the Sanity can not be reached. It seems like the secret is missing. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: where do you connect to Sanity? Is it inside `_app.js`? Or some other component?

Comment: Do you want the sanity token to be inlined in your deployed bundle?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use Next's [runtime configuration](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#runtime-configuration). Since you're dealing with a secret token, you will want to use `serverRuntimeConfig`
that is only available on the server side:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // either inline or get from env variable
    SANITY_TOKEN: process.env.SANITY_TOKEN,
    SANITY_TOKEN: "alternatively stored in this file"
  }
}
```

In your server-side coe you can then access `SANITY_TOKEN` like this:

```js
// server-side only
import getConfig from "next/config";
const { SANITY_TOKEN } = getConfig().serverRuntimeConfig;
```

However, this code will crash if you try to run it on the client side, so you'll have to
ensure it [only runs on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950309/next-js-how-to-make-all-requests-server-side)
(see also [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5354)).

---

Note that your `now.json` file let's you control which env variables are used [when deploying to ZEIT Now](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/advanced/configuration), but
does not affect your local builds (such as `$ npm run dev` and `$ npm run build`).

Thus you must set the env variable some other way when running Next locally.